# Send data to firebase and return to index.html

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am sending some data to **Firebase Database** with a javascript form and I need the page to return to the `index.html` after I get confirmation that the data was saved, here's what I've got:

### JavaScript

```
 btnAsset.addEventListener('click', e =>{
  const name = inputName.value;
  const model = inputModel.value;
  var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("Assets");
  rootRef.child(name).child("model").set(model);
});
```

### HTML Inputs

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Asset Name">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputResp" placeholder="Owner">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [`firebase.Promise`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.Promise) returned by the [`Reference.set(value)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#set) method. For instance:

```
rootRef.child(name).child("model").set(model)
    .then(function() {
        console.log('Synchronization succeeded');
        // Return to index.html here...
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log('Synchronization failed');
    });
```

also a good idea to add this to the end of your `btnAsset` listener (see Jon Jacques comment for further details):

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: Also, you'll probably want to add a `e.preventDefault()` to the end of your btn listener, as the default behavior of a button is to submit the form. And if no form submit is present, the page will reload. Based on the way OP described the issue, I would imagine that is happening here as well.

Comment: @JonJaques Good catch! Answer updated and thanks for the feedback.